# Check subtree using post order

Tags: java, tree

I'm trying to write a program to check if a Tree T2 is a subtree present in Tree T1. I'm using a traversal by storing the state of the tree into a string and checking if T2's substring is a substring present in T1's substring. 
For some reason, my code fails if I do an in-order in the traverse method to generate a string to hold the representation for the binary tree. Why does this happen? It works fine doing a Post-Order. This is the input case my program fails on:

{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}

The binary tree representation format can be found http://www.lintcode.com/help/binary-tree-representation/

```
public class Solution {
/*
 * @param T1: The roots of binary tree T1.
 * @param T2: The roots of binary tree T2.
 * @return: True if T2 is a subtree of T1, or false.
 */
public boolean isSubtree(TreeNode T1, TreeNode T2) {
    // write your code here
    if(T1 == null && T2 == null) return true;
    if(T1 == null) return false;
    if(T2 == null) return true;
    StringBuilder sbT1 = new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder sbT2 = new StringBuilder("");
    traverse(T1, sbT1);
    traverse(T2, sbT2);
    return sbT1.toString().indexOf(sbT2.toString()) != -1;
}

public void traverse(TreeNode a, StringBuilder sb) {
    if(a == null) {
        sb.append("POP");
        return;
    } else {
        traverse(a.left, sb);
        sb.append(a.val);
        traverse(a.right, sb);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: There is no reason for storing your tree in the String. Try to implement your Tree class, or just use this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: @zlakad, it's obviously an exercise that implies that the student should implement a tree and its serialization in the described form himself

Comment: The recursive algorithm you implemented does not provide the serialization of a tree in the desired order. Imagine how it works. All the items of the left subtree will always precede any of the items of the right subtree, since the right subtree will be processed after the left subtree is finished. In the form that is described at the page you mentioned, al the items of a certain level should follow each other, and the items of the next level should be processed after all the items of the given level are done. You should invent another, a little more complicated, algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive algorithm you implemented does not provide the serialization of a tree in the desired order. Imagine how it works. All the items of the left subtree will always precede any of the items of the right subtree, since the right subtree will always be processed after the left subtree is finished. In the form that is described at the page you mentioned, al the items of a certain level should follow each other, and the items of the next level should be processed after all the items of the given level are done. To write trees in the described order you need a more complicated algorithm.

And furtermore, the described way to represent a tree as a string does not allow to search for subtrees by simply searching substrings. Consider the follwing tree:

```
     1
   /    \
  2      3
 / \    / \
4   5  6   7
```

It has a subtree

```
    3
   / \ 
  6   7
```

But the string "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" does not contain "3,6,7".

A simpler and a more straightforward way to find a subtree in a tree is to do it with trees directly, without converting them into strings.

In order to slightly exercise my inventiveness I have thought out a recursive  algorithm that should convert a tree into a string using the described rules, and implemented a simple algorithm to search a subtree directly, so you can make sure that

- The subtree of a tree in a string form is not a substring of the corresponding string for the whole tree;
- Searching for subtrees in trees is much simpler than converting the trees into strings, even if the conversion algorithm allows for searching substrings in resulting strings:

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class So_47736214 {

  static String[][] testData = {
    {"1,2,3,4,5,#,6,#,#,7,8", "4,5,6"},                 // Does not contain
    {"1,2,3,4,5,#,6,#,#,7,8", "1,2,3,4,5,#,6,#,#,7,8"}, // Are equal 
    {"1,2,3,4,5,#,6,#,#,7,8", "2,4,5"},         // Contains in the left subtree   
    {"1,2,3,4,5,#,6,#,#,7,8", "3,#,6,#,7"},     // Contains in the right subtree 
    {"7,8,9", "10,11,12"},                      // Have nothing in common       
  };


  static class TreeItem {
    int value; TreeItem left; TreeItem right;
    TreeItem(int v) { this.value = v; }
  }

  static TreeItem tree1, tree2; // To hold the two trees to be compared

  /** Converts a string to a tree */
  private static TreeItem deserialize(String s) { 
    // First, prepare the layers of the tree as AttayLists containing items with values
    String[] ss = s.split(","); if (ss.length < 2) return null; // a separate string for each item 
    int pos = 0, len = 1;                       // Start position of the next layer and its length
    ArrayList<ArrayList<TreeItem>> layers = new ArrayList<>(); // A structure to hold the tree layers
    while (pos < ss.length) {
      String[] layerStrings = Arrays.copyOfRange(ss, pos, pos + len); // Strings for the next layer 
      ArrayList<TreeItem> layerItems = new ArrayList<>();             // Container for the layer's items  
      for (int i = 0; i < layerStrings.length; i++) 
        layerItems.add( ( layerStrings[i] == null || layerStrings[i].equals("#") ) ? 
          null : new TreeItem(Integer.parseInt(layerStrings[i])));    // Fill with items or nulls 
      layers.add(layerItems);
      pos += len; len *= 2;       // Start pos and lengths of the next layer
    }
    // Now the 2-d array of items is built. Establish links between an item and its subtrees 
    ArrayList<TreeItem> prevLayer = layers.get(0);  
    for (int i = 1; i < layers.size(); i++) { // Start from 1 -- skip layer 0  
      ArrayList<TreeItem> layer = layers.get(i);
      for (int j = 0; j < prevLayer.size(); j++ ) {
        TreeItem prevLayerItem = prevLayer.get(j);
        if (prevLayerItem != null) {
          prevLayerItem.left = layer.get(j * 2);      // left subtree is a next layer's item 
          prevLayerItem.right = layer.get(j * 2 + 1); // right subtree
        }
      };
      prevLayer = layer;
    }
    return layers.get(0).get(0); // The tree is ready. It's the root
  }

  private static void deserialize(String s1, String s2) {
    tree1 = deserialize(s1); 
    tree2 = deserialize(s2); 
  }

  static int levelCount;

  /** Puts the item into the appropriate position in the list of the layers 
   * and recursively processes the item's subtrees */  
  private static void insertItem(TreeItem item, ArrayList<TreeItem[]> layerList, int idx, int level) {
    TreeItem[] levelItems;
    if (layerList.size() < level + 1)  // Needs to create a new array for the level
      layerList.add(levelItems = new TreeItem[1 << level]); // size of the array = pow(2, level)  
    else                            
      levelItems = layerList.get(level);
    levelItems[idx] = item;
    idx *= 2; level++;
    if (item.left != null)
      insertItem(item.left, layerList, idx, level);
    if (item.right != null)
      insertItem(item.right, layerList, idx+ 1, level);
  }

  /** Writes the values from the list of layers into a string */ 
  private static String arraysToString(ArrayList<TreeItem[]> layerList) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int strLen = 0;  
    for (TreeItem[] layer: layerList) 
      for (int i = 0; i < layer.length; i++) 
        if (layer[i] != null) {
          sb.append(layer[i].value + ",");
          strLen = sb.length();
        } else 
          sb.append("#,");
    return sb.length() == 0? "" : sb.substring(0, strLen - 1);
  }

  /** Converts a tree into a string */
  private static String serialize(TreeItem tree) {
    ArrayList<TreeItem[]> items = new ArrayList<>();
    levelCount = 0;
    insertItem(tree, items, 0, 0);
    return arraysToString(items); 
  }

  /** Converts a pair of trees into strings and look for substrings */  
  private static void test1(TreeItem t1, TreeItem t2) {
    System.out.println("Test1:");
    String s1 = serialize(t1), s2 = serialize(t2);
    String result = s1.contains(s2)? "contains" : "doesn't contain"; 
    System.out.format("  '%s' %s '%s'\n", s1, result, s2);
  }

  /** Checks if the trees are equal */
  private static boolean areEqual(TreeItem t1, TreeItem t2) {
    if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false; 
    return (areEqual(t1.left, t2.left) && areEqual(t1.right, t2.right)); 
  }

  /** Checks if t2 is a subtree of t1 */  
  private static boolean contains(TreeItem t1, TreeItem t2) {
    if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
    if (t1 == null) return false; 
    if (t2 == null) return true; 
    if ( t1.value == t2.value 
          && areEqual(t1.left, t2.left)
          && areEqual(t1.left, t2.left)) 
      return true;
    return (contains(t1.left, t2) || contains(t1.right, t2));
  }

  /** Checks if t1 is a subtree of t1, and shows the result */ 
  private static void test2(TreeItem t1, TreeItem t2) {
    System.out.println("Test2:");
    String s1 = serialize(t1), s2 = serialize(t2);
    String result = (contains(t1, t2)? "contains" : "doesn't contain"); 
    System.out.format("  '%s' %s '%s'\n", s1, result, s2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // runs the two tests through the test dataset
    for (int i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
      deserialize(testData[i][0], testData[i][1]); // converts strings into trees  
      test1(tree1, tree2);      // looks if t1 is a subtree of t1, using string representations  
      test2(tree1, tree2);      // looks if t1 is a subtree of t1, directly with trees
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If you mean the height of the tree by n, yes. The quantity of the items in a tree is in proportion to the square of its height, just like with triangles. But if you mean the number of items, then O(n). It has no extra loops except traversing the items.